# Matrix dimension + loop error in Matlab

Tags: loops, matrix, dimension

I have a vector "Xt" where Xt dimensions are 12588 X 1. From this vector I apply this code:

`S=sum((abs(Xt(2:end)-Xt(1:end-1))).^2);`

which result in one number where S is a 1by1.

Now my objective is to construct a vector S (Nx1) where each value in S depends on J and K -- for instance:

`S=sum((abs(Xt(**J**:end)-Xt(**K**:end-1))).^2);`

At first I thought of the following (I don't want J do exceed 126):

`for j=2:126 k=1:125,
S=sum((abs(Xt(j:end)-Xt(1:end-k))).^2);
end;
end;`

I got the error: "Error using  - 
Matrix dimensions must agree."

Is it a dimension issue plus a loop issue?

---

I just realized that this code works

```
for j=2:2 k=1:1;
```

S=sum((abs(Xt(j:end)-Xt(1:end-k))).^2);
end;

so it is really a matrix dimension issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close this question:

that is how I solved this little problem 2 weeks ago:

```
for j=2:2 k=1:1;
S=sum((abs(Xt(j:end)-Xt(1:end-k))).^2); end;
```

very simple

(I was new to Matlab)